# Problem with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I know I'm asking the same question asked before by other users, but I want to know if there is any page in Stack Overflow that solves my problem.

I have a Database Configuration class defined like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {AppConfig.CLASS_REPOSITORIES})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLog(AppConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    AppConfig config;

    //Bean methods
}
```

The constant `AppConfig.CLASS_REPOSITORIES` is defined in an Application Configuration class defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({AppConfig.CLASS_SERVICES,AppConfig.CLASS_WEB, AppConfig.CLASS_WEBCORE}) 
@Import({DatabaseConfig.class, WebConfig.class, DBIccidsConfig.class, DBOabiConfig.class})
public class AppConfig  {
    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLog(AppConfig.class);
    /**************************************************/

    /**************************************************/
    public static final  String CONS_APP_CONFIG      =  Constants.NAME.toUpperCase();    
    public static final  String CLASS_SERVICES       = "cl.claro.berrws.business.services";
    public static final  String CLASS_WEB            = "cl.claro.berrws.soap.controllers";
    public static final  String CLASS_WEBCORE        = "cl.claro.berrws.soap.core";
    public static final  String CLASS_REPOSITORIES   = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.repositories";
    public static final  String CLASS_ENTITIES       = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities";
    public static final  String CLASS_ICCIDS_REPOSITORIES   = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.iccids.repositories";
    public static final  String CLASS_ICCIDS_ENTITIES       = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.iccids.entities";   
    public static final  String CLASS_OABI_REPOSITORIES   = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.imeioabi.repositories";
    public static final  String CLASS_OABI_ENTITIES       = "cl.claro.berrws.persistence.imeioabi.entities";   

//Bean methods that are not relevant for this problem
```

The constant `CLASS_REPOSITORIES` points to the package `cl.claro.berrws.persistence.iccids.repositories` that contains two repository interfaces. One of them is `EstadoRepository`, defined as follows:

```
package cl.claro.berrws.persistence.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities.Estado;

@Repository
public interface EstadoRepository extends JpaRepository<Estado, String>{
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Estado e WHERE e.imei=:imei")
    public Estado obtieneEstado(@Param("imei") String imei);
}
```

The class `Estado` exists in the package `cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities` referenced by the constant `CLASS_ENTITIES` in the `AppConfig` class. The class `Estado` is defined like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_ESTADOS")
@XmlRootElement
public class Estado implements Serializable {
    //Some attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IMEI", length=20)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String imei;

    //More attributes
}
```

The order of the attributes is established in the database (an Oracle Database)

The `DatabaseConfig` class defines the Bean methods that uses the entity classes as follows:

```
@Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) LOG.info("Configurando ENTITY MANAGER");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(AppConfig.CLASS_ENTITIES);
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",Config.getConfig("hibernate.dialect"));        
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",Config.getConfig("hibernate.showSql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",Config.getConfig("hibernate.format_sql")); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",Config.getConfig("hibernate.hbm2ddl")); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",true); 
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);        
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Still, when I execute my application, i get the following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities.Estado`

Did I missed something?
Thanks in advance, folks.

P.D.: The application also uses Maven. I don't know if it is relevant.

Comment: if you try to use entities inside the package **cl.claro.berrws.persistence.iccids.entities** do its works?

Comment: The package you mentioned is being used by another Database Configuration class pointing to another database. I cannot move the Estado entity class to that package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue occurs because the bean for your class `cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities.Estado` is not getting created. In your DatabaseConfig .class you are only specifying the package `AppConfig.CLASS_REPOSITORIES` to be scanned so, try adding the following :

```
@ComponentScan("cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities")
```

so that the entity classes are also picked up by spring. So your configuration should be like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("cl.claro.berrws.persistence.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {AppConfig.CLASS_REPOSITORIES})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLog(AppConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    AppConfig config;

    //Bean methods
}
```

or you could try specifying the entity class package using the `@EntityScan` annotation like :

```
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"domain"} )
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but no avail. The problem remains

Comment: @mrcoar Have you tried using @EntityScan( basePackages = {"domain"} ) annotation ?

Comment: In fact, I resolved this problem some days ago, but StackOverflow does not let me answer my own question :( How do i do to tell you what I did?

Comment: @mrcoar You could answer your own question after two days .

Comment: i got this message from StackOverflow: We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.